# Parcel Error : Cannot resolve entry. But i cross checked the file is there where it is supposed to be. Its not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the code.
It says : Cannot resolve entry "D:\study[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\public\js\index.js" from
"D:\study[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\public\js"
at Bundler.bundle (D:\study[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:268:19)

This is how the error looks like:
[image]

```
D:\study\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter>npm run watch:js

> nators@1.0.0 watch:js D:\study\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter
> parcel watch ./public/js/index.js

×  Cannot resolve entry "D:\study\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\public\js\index.js" from 
"D:\study\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\public\js"
    at Bundler.bundle (D:\study\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More The Complete Bootcamp 2020\4-natours\starter\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:268:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nators@1.0.0 watch:js: `parcel watch ./public/js/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nators@1.0.0 watch:js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VISHWAJEET\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T06_19_06_280Z-debug.log
```

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning Node, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose, Pug and building the natours project along the way",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production& nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
    "build:js": "parcel watch ./public/js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "Vishwajeet Raj",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.0.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "ndb": "^1.1.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "slugify": "^1.4.0",
    "validator": "^12.2.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the Project in Drive:C without node_modules and then do npm install and your next command in your command prompt!